# Checking a file against itself

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that checks how many words are inside of other words. Then tell the user which word has the most words in it.  For some reason, the while loop is breaking and I cannot get the file to reload. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct finalWord {
    string word;
    int number;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const finalWord& f) {
    return o << f.word << ": " << f.number;
}

int main () {

    finalWord f;
    string line, holder, line2;
    ifstream myFile("enable1.txt");
    int counter;
    int holdlen;
    size_t found;
    if (myFile.is_open()){
        while(getline(myFile,line)){
            holder = line;
            while (getline(myFile, line)){
                found = holder.find(line);
                if (found != string::npos){
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter > holdlen) {
                    f.word = line;
                    f.number = counter;
                    holdlen = counter;
                }
                counter = 0;

            }

        }
    }

    cout << f << endl;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to first read all the words into a `std::vector` so you can work with them easily.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of doing this but was not sure if there was a way I could do it without loading the whole list into memory.

Comment: @Jiegend: It is possible, but you would need to re-open the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem you are facing is because of the two loops you are using with same **myFile**

```
IN First WHILE loop it will take a word

IN Second WHILE loop it will go through the rest of the file.
```

It will be an issue in the following case.

```
If a String "I am Happy" is occurred more than once then it will iterate for each occurrence to search up to end of the file.

So to avoid that you need to take the unique strings in an vector as said by Vaughn Cato and then do a check for the occurrence of that string in the whole file to make it efficient.
```